# Prevent warming up instances to serve requests when scaling out Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, horizontal-scaling

We host our Asp.Net app as Azure App Service and using scaling-out capabilities. The issue is that when we add new instances these new instances start to server requests almost immediately - before warming up process is done. I am using **application initialization** module with the following configuration:

```
  <applicationInitialization remapManagedRequestsTo="/warmup.html">  
     <add initializationPage="/start.ashx" />  
  </applicationInitialization>
```

And once we scale-out the plan e.g. from 3 instances to 4 and requesting the site, approximately 1 of 4 times I see my warmup.html - therefore I assume that newly created instance considered by the balancer before it is actually warmed up.

Please note: our site does not require HTTPS, so [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/site-behavior-performance/application-fail-ssl-web) should not be an issue.

The question: how can we prevent warming up instances from being requested until the are ready to serve requests?